# Rotate image without altering the size or format

Tags: vb.net

I have a JPG image that is about 500 KB in size and I would like to rotate the image 90 to the right.. when I rotate this image with (windows photo viewer) the size or format stays the same..

```
            Dim newImage As Image = Image.FromFile(imageName)
            newImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone)
            newImage.Save(imageName)
```

when I use this code the format changes from JPG into PNG and also size of 500 KB goes to 1.5MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will change its format depending on your code for saving the result image.

That being said, you won't be able to do a losless JPG transformation with .NET alone. You must open, rotate and save-with-encoding.

Some desktop apps like ACDSee offer losless JPG rotation, but they go about it on a deeper level.

Let's take a step back: Why do you need to rotate the image? Is it a portrait which maybe contains the rotation information from the camera? Then, other imaging libraries like FreeImage should be investigated, as they can open JPGs and do the rotating automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the image is recoded. I can not see anything in the documentation saying that [`RotateFlip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.rotateflip.aspx) should be lossless.

A quick tour with Google gives [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/64116/Using-GDIplus-code-in-a-WPF-application-for-lossle.aspx) that you might try.

JPEG images are compressed and when you change something in the image you need to redo the compression, at least for the edited parts. For 90° rotation there is this special lossless trick you can use, but that won't be applied if you just rotate the image and tries compresses the result. You need to use the magic trick. If you want to remove the compression, save as BMP or use a lossless compression like PNG.